# pivot table in MS SQL server without ascending/integer ID

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i have a problem with pivoting a table within ms-sql-server. i have tried different things with PIVOT, but i am not getting it and still have problems to get it right.

maybe it's because I have no ascending ID number in the table.
it's been a while that i worked with sql but i am really stuck right now and hoped, that there is someone out there to help me with this thing.

i start with this table:

```
id  no1  no2    name    state
-------------------------------
11  5503 NULL   alf     0
11  8533 X1705  ben     0
11  2716 X0608  cha     1
11  5263 X0811  cha     2
11  3158 X0603  cha     2
12  5503 NULL   alf     0
12  8533 X1705  ben     0
12  3158 X0603  cha     2
12  2716 X0608  cha     1
12  5263 X0811  cha     2
13  8731 NULL   alf     0
13  8732 X1705  ben     0
13  4407 X1307  cha     1
14  8247 NULL   alf     0
14  7128 X1705  ben     0
14  5535 X1403  cha     1
14  7281 X9812  cha     0
```

and i would like to receive a pivoted table

```
id,no1,no2,name,state,no1,no2,name,state,no1,no2,name,state,no1,no2,name,state, …
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12,5503,NULL,alf,0,8533,X1705,ben,0,3158,X0603,cha,2,2716,X0608,5263,X0811,cha,2
13,8731,NULL,alf,0,8732,X1705,ben,0,4407,X1307,cha,1
14,8247,NULL,alf,0,7128,X1705,ben,0,5535,X1403,cha,1,7281,X9812,cha,0
```

there is #always one "name" with "alf" and "ben" for each id
but there can be up to max. 4 entries in "name" with "cha"

so basically, i want to "group" the data sets based on the column "ID" - which is not the id for each data set. but i don't have an int, only a uniqueidentifier (not shown in this example) and i don't see any column, where i can use an aggregate function like "sum" or "avg". can/should i use "max"?
is this even possible with pivot?

Comment: Make your source query into a derived table. Add a second derived table such as

Comment: 2nd try: Make your source query into a derived table. Add a second derived table such as `SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY id) as rnum FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM MyTable WHERE (... conditions...))`.  Join the tables, pivot on the new `rnum` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no logic to use `PIVOT` here. You seem to need just to restructure the data on rows by id. I would do this:

```
WITH
  s1 AS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE name = 'alf')
, s2 AS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE name = 'ben')
, sc AS (SELECT *, rn = row_number() over( partition by id, name order by (SELECT NULL) )
    from sample WHERE name = 'cha')
, s3 AS (SELECT * FROM sc WHERE rn = 1)
, s4 AS (SELECT * FROM sc WHERE rn = 2)
, s5 AS (SELECT * FROM sc WHERE rn = 3)

SELECT s1.* 
    , s2.no1, s2.no2, s2.name, s2.state
    , s3.no1, s3.no2, s3.name, s3.state
    , s4.no1, s4.no2, s4.name, s4.state
    , s5.no1, s5.no2, s5.name, s5.state
    FROM s1
      LEFT JOIN s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
      LEFT JOIN s3 ON s1.id = s3.id
      LEFT JOIN s4 ON s1.id = s4.id
      LEFT JOIN s5 ON s1.id = s5.id
;
```

Comment: hi,
sorry, i didn't have time to thank you for your answer.
it solved my problem real quick!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a query like below; I've used PARSENAME as you only have upto 4 names in an id. In case there are more you'd need an actual string splitter function

<kbd>**[Here's a live demo too!](http://rextester.com/AKYMQ50006)**</kbd>

```
select 
id,
no1   =PARSENAME ([1],4),
no2   =PARSENAME ([1],3),
name  =PARSENAME ([1],2),
state =PARSENAME ([1],1),
no1   =PARSENAME ([2],4),
no2   =PARSENAME ([2],3),
name  =PARSENAME ([2],2),
state =PARSENAME ([2],1),
no1   =PARSENAME ([3],4),
no2   =PARSENAME ([3],3),
name  =PARSENAME ([3],2),
state =PARSENAME ([3],1),
no1   =PARSENAME ([4],4),
no2   =PARSENAME ([4],3),
name  =PARSENAME ([4],2),
state =PARSENAME ([4],1)
from
(
    select 
        id, 
        newcol= concat(no1,'.',no2,'.',name,'.',state),
        rn    = row_number() over( partition by id order by (select null))
    from sample
 )src
PIVOT
 ( 
     max(newcol) 
         for rn in 
             ([1],[2],[3],[4])
  )p
```

Comment: thanks for your help (and sorry for the late feedback).
i used @edixons approach (below) without pivot.

Comment: @jhaslauer You should upvote and mark edixons answer as answer to close the question